# GitHub + Do not merge PRs with unresolved conversations

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to add a rule so the PR with open conversations can not be merged.
It occurs that I can find a typo in PR and add a comment and still approve the PR, so that an author has the opportunity to quickly correct this typo and merge the PR.
But I want it to be impossible to merge the PR until an author resolves the conversation.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like they've added a branch rule option for this but it indicates that the functionality is still in Beta.

Simply go to `Settings` -> `Branches` and check the `Require conversation resolution before merging` field.

[image: Require conversation resolution before merging field.]

Comment: Is there any way to make it a warning instead of a hard blocker?

Comment: Similarly, is there a way to make it blocker instead of a warning? Right now it seems optional.

Comment: @Bradley Not sure if this was the case last month, but yes, if the settings box is checked, merging will be blocked, even if the "unresolved" comment comes from an approving review.

Comment: Blocked in what sense though. What I see is that it shows up as a red X but the big green merge button is still present. So it's more of a soft-block.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to do that.  Conversations and review comments aren't considered when performing merge checks.

If you want to prevent the PR from being merged, then you need to refrain from approving it or request changes if need be.  The reason is that conversations can be resolved entirely by one party, so they aren't very effective at ensuring the user has done anything about them.  The author could resolve it and merge without making any changes at all, and therefore it doesn't make sense to make this any sort of control.